# Make scrollbars disappear in PerformancePoint Strategy Map

Tags: performancepoint

I have a PerformancePoint 2007 strategy map that displays in Visio Viewer within the browser.  I can right-click the map and hide the toolbar & the scrollbars.  When I refresh they come back.  How do I set the default view of Visio Viewer to hide the toolbar and the scrollbars?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the activex based version I believe that there is no way to set this. But you have the option to use a image instead of activex. In that case there will be no scroll bars.

PPS is no longer continued by Microsoft. It will be a part of SharePoint Enterprise edition now. Hope these bugs are fixed in that version.